# Automatically create an account for new customer

Tags: web3js, contract-design, dapp-development, eoa

I would like to automatically create an account (EOA) in Ethereum for all the users of my platform as soon as they register.
Is it possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but key management is an issue. It's a tradeoff between simplicity and responsibility. Either you manage their keys and make their lives easier, but take full responsibility, Or you only ask for an ethereum address, and let them deal with account creation.

A nice solution seems to be [Metamask](https://metamask.io)'s approach.

I am actually planning to use their service for my next project. They can deal with the account, and you can focus on your app.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your platform, most implementations of ethereum offer a way to create a keypair, which allows you to access an address (derived from public) using your private key.

**An example in EthereumJ**

```
private ECKey generateRawKey() {
    return new ECKey(new SecureRandom());
}
```